# When can I check if an '@Input()' has been given?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to check if there is an @Input() given by another component which is using my component. But I don´t know when I can check this? Should I check it in 'ngOnInit', 'ngAfterViewInit' or something else?

Comment: Check before `use`!

Comment: Is there no way to check it in the angular lifecyle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check that by implementing `ngOnChanges` with something like this:

```js
export class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() input;
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.hasOwnProperty('input')) {
      if (changes['input'].isfirstChange()) { // AKA initialization by angular
        doStuff();
      } else { // Real change due to your logic
        doMoreStuff();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could check in both `ngOnInit` or `ngAfterViewInit`, but you cannot know for sure if the expected data will be there (maybe the input data comes from a HTTP call or is the result of some calculation).

I would suggest implementing the `OnChanges` interface and using `ngOnChanges` as it triggers on any input data change.

From the docs,

> A callback method that is invoked immediately after the default change
>   detector has checked data-bound properties if at least one has
>   changed, and before the view and content children are checked.

https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

Answer (score 0):

What are you exactly trying to use the @Input() for?
becouse if you are trying to pass the input through various components(child, sibling and parent alike) i'd much more advise using services, also they're much easier to check than input(in my personal opinion).

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: I´m using it for passing data throw other components which use my component. It should be simple as possible and accessible in the whole application and so I decided to use @Input() instead of a service. I have a lot of other services(are used for communication with a server) in my app and so I wanted to access the data throw inputs.